# Flutter: Floating Button in Front of Other Apps

Tags: button, flutter, floating

how can i achive a floating action button in front of all other apps?

A java example could be: https://www.journaldev.com/14673/android-floating-widget.

What flutter widget can i use for that. Maybe there are some examples with flutter (didn't found any).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the similar action using [`Draggable`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) widget but that will work only inside the app and inside same `Stateful`/`Stateless` widget.

The reason why "drawing over other apps" is not possible in Flutter till yet is because iOS does not support this functionality. You can always log an issue at [Flutter's GitHub repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues)

Comment: I am a beginner on mobile development and with flutter even more. And this is an interesting point, which i have not thought about before. By using a single framework for both android and ios (flutter) I can be limited in functions because i can use only those things that are usable for both operating systems. The "floating button in front of all apps" is just one little thing.  There could be many more things that won't work with flutter.

Comment: Everything has its caveats too :)

Comment: Doesn't Facebook Messanger has this functionality on iOS?

Comment: @Undefitied nope, it's called "App Overlay" and is available only on Android.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from restriction that it won't work on IOS, there is a plugin in flutter which does the trick [System Alert Window](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/system_alert_window)

It shows Truecaller like overlay window, over all other apps along with callback events